# Pinch to zoom inside particular shape in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, shapes

I am having `custom ImageView`, in which I have to set image inside `custom shape` like polygon, star, etc. I have successfully added image inside custom shape. But now I want to perform `pinch to zoom` on image. Only image should be able to zoom and shape should remain as it is. I am not getting how should I proceed further.

Below is the code which I have used for setting image inside shape:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (!isInitialized) {
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            position.set(w / 2, h / 2);
            isInitialized = true;
        }

        transform.reset();
        transform.postTranslate(-width / 2.0f, -height / 2.0f);
        transform.postRotate(getDegreesFromRadians(angle));

        if (scale > 1)
            transform.postScale(scale, scale);

        transform.postTranslate(position.getX(), position.getY());

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        mCanvas.drawBitmap(src, transform, null);// bg

        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);// object
        paint.setXfermode(null);

        canvas.drawBitmap(result, 0, 0, paint);
    }
```

[image]  [image]

**EDIT :**
Using above code, somewhat image has been able to translate and zoom. But problem that is coming is - it shows repeated drawings on canvas. I dont know why it is showing like this.

Please provide me some help/guidance on how to proceed further.
Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: abd you want to create a Bitmap each time you perform any zoom gesture? it will be damn slow

Comment: I have written this masking code in constructor. then in `onDraw`, I am drawing Bitmap. Am I going wrong ?

Comment: you don't need a Bitmap, you can use Canvas.saveLayer

Comment: But how I should perform pinch to zoom only on image which is inside shape ??

Comment: Canvas.scale or draw yor image with Matrix parameter

Comment: @pskink Please review my edited code. Can you please help me out ?

Comment: what's  "repeated drawings"?

Comment: wait i am attaching image for better understanding.

Comment: @pskink Please check my updated image. If I am zooming center part of image, then no issue is coming. This happens when I am zooming border area of image. I dont know what I am missing or where I am going wrong.

Comment: most likely you don't  clear the tmp bitmap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55038/discussion-between-dig-and-pskink). Please help me out.

Comment: @dig Hey are you able to find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.zoom:
            Intent zoomIntent = new Intent(con, ImageViewer.class);
            JSONObject jImage;
            try {
                jImage = new JSONObject(jbImage.getString(swiped));
                if(jImage!=null){
                    Log.d("Inventory Cars Details::::::","JImage Lentgh"+jImage.length());
                    String url=jImage.getString("imageURL");
                    if(url!=null){
                        Log.d("Inventory Cars Details::::::","Url Not Null"+jImage.length());
                        if(!url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
                            Log.d("Inventory Cars Details::::::","Url string is not Null::"+url);
                            zoomIntent.putExtra("image", jImage.getString("imageURL"));
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Inventory Cars Details::::::","Url string is Null::"+url);
                            zoomIntent.putExtra("image", commonImageURL);
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.d("Inventory Cars Details::::::","Url is Null::");
                        zoomIntent.putExtra("image", commonImageURL);
                    }
                }else{
                    zoomIntent.putExtra("image", commonImageURL);
                }
                zoomIntent.putExtra("title",
                        jb.getString("year") + " " + jb.getString("c_make")
                        + " " + jb.getString("s_model"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            startActivityForResult(zoomIntent,DealershipApplication.REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the above code for zooming your image. It will not suits you completely, just take the functionality which you want for your app.

Comment: please refer the question properly. I dont think its related to my question in any way.